# MVC 4: Multiple Controller action parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

Instead of just `{controller}/{action}/{id}` is it possible to have mulitple parameters like 
`{controller}/{action}/{id}/{another id}`?

I'm new to MVC (coming from just plain Web Pages). If not possible, does MVC provide a helper method like the `UrlData` availble in Web Pages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will just need to map the new route in your global.asax, like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "NewRoute", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{another_id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, another_id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);
```

Then in your controller's action you can pick up the parameter like this:

```
public ActionResult MyAction(string id, string another_id)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: You should add that first id to your action method parameter list :  public ActionResult MyAction(string id, string another_id) so that both ids are used by the example action.

Comment: I've been trying this on IIS express and full IIS 7 but get Error 404.0 with a 2nd parameter. I tried reading http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/deployment/using-asp-net-mvc-with-different-versions-of-iis-cs but nothing helped. Any suggestions?

Comment: @DavidHyogo you need to have exact same names for action parameters in controller action handler as in route. so above MyAction(string id, string another_id) literally can't be MyAction(string customerId, string otherId).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can define multiple parameters in a route.  You will need to first define your route in your Global.asax file.  You can define parameters in URL segments, or in portions of URL segments.  To use your example, you can define a route as

```
{controller}/{action}/{id1}/{id2}
```

the MVC infrastructure will then parse matching routes to extract the id1 and id2 segments and assign them to the corresponding variables in your action method:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
   public ActionResult Index(string id1, string id2)
  {
    //..
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you could also accept input parameters from query string or form variables.  For example:

```
MyController/Index/5?id2=10
```

Routing is discussed in more detail [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx#url_patterns)